# Dozer UUID mapping

Tags: java, uuid, dozer

I am trying to map a UUID field using Dozer, and running into a problem mentioned on dozer github:

https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/83

the problem is - apparently, Dozer relies on a default no-parameter constructor, which is not present in UUID. So, the link shows how to tell Dozer to perform reference copy instead. However, using that hint doesn't help, I am still getting this exception:

> org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   java.util.UUID.()

The test failing ins this:

```
@Test
public void testUUIDMapping() {
    UUID source = fakeUUID1;

    UUID result = mapper.map(source, UUID.class);

    Assert.assertEquals(result, source);
}
```

Finally, the mappings is this, as per the hint in the issues:

```
<configuration>
    <copy-by-references>
        <copy-by-reference>java.util.UUID</copy-by-reference>
    </copy-by-references>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use String to store UUID? Why do you need UUID class once the proper value is generated?

Comment: This is not the point; let's just assume there is a need to use UUID (in my case, there is, and there's no nice way around it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a mapper to map from a UUID to another UUID?  Shouldn't you be testing that you can map a UUID from class A to class B?  When you map the UUID *directly*, dozer is going to reflectively inspect the fields inside the UUID and try to copy them from one to another.

In other words, I don't think this test is valid.  This test passed for me (it needed the configuration you added):

```
@Test
public void whenMappingAUuidThenItGetsCopiedByReference() {
    ClassWithUuid a = new ClassWithUuid();
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    a.setUuid(uuid);

    Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
    ClassWithUuid b = //map to b
    assertEquals(uuid, b.getUuid());
}

public static class ClassWithUuid {
    private UUID uuid;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Intereting! Yeah I've tried a 'simpler' test, without realizing this isn't how Dozer works (my first time with it). Thanks, I will try to make a proper test, where UUIDs will be properties of mapped classes.